# Proper effective étale groupoid gives an effective orbifold

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

[image]
[image]

I have a question about the translation groupoid mentioned in the last paragraph. I don't understand why $N_x/G_x$ is an open embedding.

I think because $X$ is the orbit space, we need to mod out by those elements in $G_1$ that map elements in $N_x$ to $N_x$. It seems to me that those elements are just the union of $O_g$ where $g \in G_x$, whereas $G_x$ is just a subset of this union.

Comment: This proposition is taken from the book [*Orbifolds and Stringy Topology*](https://books.google.de/books?id=AsaCDk9N0LAC&pg=PA21) by Adem, Leida, Ruan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have $h \in G_1$ such that $s(h),t(h) \in N_x$, then, indeed, $h \in O_g \subseteq W_g$ for some $g \in G_x$. Furthermore, by definition, we have $g \cdot s(h) = \tilde{g}(s(h)) = t(h)$, so that the action of $G_x$ on $N_x$ acts just as wanted: it identifies objects $a,b \in N_x$ precisely if there is an isomorphism between them.

Comment: I can see that $G_x$ identifies elements in $N_x$. But by definition, $O_g$ also identifies elements in $N_x$, right? What if two elements are identified by $O_g$ for some $g$, but not by $G_x$?

Comment: If two elements $a,b \in N_x$ are "identified by $O_g$" for some $g \in G_x$, in the sense that there is an $h \in O_g$ such that $s(h)=a$ and $t(h)=b$, then we have $g \cdot a = b$, so that they are also "identified by $G_x$". Note that the elements in $O_g$, for a given $g \in G_x$, and the group $G_x$ identify objects in $N_x$ in a different way: the isomorphisms $h \in O_g \subseteq G_1$ identify $s(h)$ with $t(h)$, whereas $G_x$ *acts* on $N_x$, i.e. $g \in G_x$ identifies $a \in N_x$ with $g \cdot a$.

Comment: Conversely, if $a,b \in N_x$ are "identified by $G_x$", in the sense that there is a $g \in G_x$ such that $g \cdot a = b$, then, by definition, there is an $h \in W_g$ such that $s(h)=a$ and $t(h)=b$, and $h \in O_g$, i.e. $a,b$ are also "identified by $O_g$".

Comment: Now I see. Thank you.